# Why does the insertion operator give a different result in std::cout when I use extra brackets without operator overloading?

Tags: c++, c++11, operators, cout, ostream

Based on my understanding, the insertion operator when used with any ostream object like an `std::cout`, will simply insert the values which follow. But when I use brackets, I am getting a different result than expected. I am trying to understand why does the usage of insertion operator with brackets in the code shown below, give the following result in C++ ?

**Code**

```
std::cout << (2 << 3) << std::endl;
```

**Result**

```
16
```

Comment: `2<<3` means *shift the digit 2 by 3 bits to the left*. So `2 << 3 = 16` and that's what's printed. To print the individuals digits, do `std::cout << 2 <<3 << '\n';`

Comment: I didn't know that the `<<` also meant a bit-shift operator in C++. All these days I thought it was only an insertion operator when used without operator overloading !

Comment: `<<` was a bit-shift operator in C before C++ ever existed. It is still a "bit-shift" operator in C++, and in a little while you will get to the chapter in your C++ book that explains what "operator overloading" means, and everything will become crystal clear.

Comment: @ArunKumar — `2<<3` uses the builtin `<<` operator. Stream inserters are all overloaded operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It becomes bitshift instead of insertion operator when you bracket it like that.

2 in binary is `10`

After a left shift of 3, the binary becomes `10000` which is equivalent to 16

Answer (score 1):

Why does the subtraction operator give a different result in math expression when I use extra brackets: `1 - (1 + 1)`? Answer: The parentheses change the order of operations.

What does it mean to insert 3 into 2? Answer: `2 << 3` is not a stream insertion operator at all. After all, 2 is not a character stream. It is the bit shift left operator. Different operators have different meanings for different types.